# How do you delete duplicate row based none primary key columns

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a table schema set up:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62d3e/1/0

Where I have couple of rows that are duplicate by field, fieldtypeid, fieldalias columns. I need to delete all rows that duplicate by these 3 columns, but have null values for "somevalue" column.

What is the easiest way of doing this? I have tried to do a MERGE Statement, but that doesn't work because merge catches the duplicates.

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(Id INT, field NVARCHAR(50), fieldType INT, fieldalias NVARCHAR(50), ForDelete BIT)
 DECLARE @B TABLE(Id INT, field NVARCHAR(50), fieldTypeId INT, fieldalias NVARCHAR(50), ForDelete BIT)

 INSERT INTO @A
 SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.field, c.fieldTypeId, c.fieldalias,0
 FROM DuplicateValues c
 WHERE c.somevalue IS NOT NULL

 INSERT INTO @B
 SELECT DISTINCT c.Id, c.field, c.fieldTypeId, c.fieldalias,0
 FROM DuplicateValues c
 WHERE c.somevalue IS NULL

 declare @T table(Id int, ForDelete BIT, Act varchar(10))


 MERGE @B AS B
 USING @A AS A
 ON A.fieldTypeId = B.fieldTypeId AND A.field = B.field AND A.fieldalias = B.fieldalias
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET B.ForDelete = 1
 WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (Id, field, fieldTypeId, fieldalias, ForDelete) VALUES(A.Id, A.field,A.fieldTypeId, A.fieldalias, 1)
 OUTPUT INSERTED.Id, INSERTED.ForDelete, $ACTION INTO @T;


 SELECT * FROM @T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your provided Fiddle schema, you can use the below query to achieve the same. See your modified fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f201/1

```
delete from DuplicateValues
where FIELD in(
  select FIELD from DuplicateValues
  group by field, fieldtypeId, fieldalias
  having count(*) > 1
  )
and somevalue is null
```

Here `group by .. having count(*) > 1` will give all the `FIELDS` which have been duplicated.

Comment: +1, added other three columns to group by as OP was expecting duplicates based on 3 columns

Answer (score 1):

Using window function with in a cte u can find duplicates. Try this

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY field, fieldtypeid, fieldalias ORDER BY id) rn, 
                * 
         FROM   duplicatevalues) 
DELETE A 
FROM   duplicatevalues a 
       JOIN cte b 
         ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE  rn > 1
```

Comment: I think join part is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Row_number() funnction like:

```
;WITH cte 
 AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER(partition BY field, fieldtypeid, fieldalias ORDER BY id) Row, 
            * 
     FROM   duplicatevalues) 
 DELETE From cte WHERE  Row> 1
```

Comment: In the question it is mentioned that "need to delete all rows that duplicate by these 3 columns" this remove the duplicates but not the duplicated ID.

Comment: "I need to delete all rows that duplicate by these 3 columns". do you check result?

Comment: I checked the result. If you want i can create a sample fiddle.If a id is duplicated by 3 columns(field, fieldtypeid, fieldalias) then it has to be deleted thats all i understood from the question. ur query will not delete all the rows of the duplicated ID.

Comment: Deleting all the rows would be an uncommon requirement. However, if you wanted to do that, just change row_number to count.